# Distribute month bars evenly in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting monthly data in a bar chart using Matplotlib. This is very easy, as Matplotlib understands dates, and will place the bar at just the right place on the timeline, e.g. [like this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html):

```py
values = [0.3, 0.1, 0.4]
dates = [datetime(1955, 1, 1), datetime(1955, 2, 1), datetime(1955, 3, 1)]
pyplot.bar(dates, values)
```

The issue with months, however, is that because months are different lengths, there will be some spacing artifacts that just looks weird (even though they are technically correct) when plotting large time series:

[image: See how February looks weird here]

How can I tell Matplotlib to distribute the 12 months evenly across each year? (If it's possible it would be nice to keep dates in the x axis input, as it allows me to use other features, like `matplotlib.dates.MonthLocator/YearLocator` etc)

Comment: Maybe you could work with variable bar widths? Those differences will be less visible. An easy way would be to make all bars a bit wider and set a white edge color which will take care of overlaps.